# Searchbar for datagrid

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

im trying to keep a searchbar for datagrid,so when the user enters certain value in search bar,the datagrid should show only entered value.i installed xamarin.forms.xamarin.i have gone through different example but no luck i did get what iam looking for.Looking forward for positive responce.
Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be achieved by putting a `SearchBar` above a ListView. Binding the `Text` value of the `SearchBar` to a property in your ViewModel enables you to handle changes to the `Text` property by querying the data.

In XAML:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <SearchBar Grid.Row="0" Text="{Binding Filter}" HeightRequest="40" />
    <ListView Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" />
</Grid>
```

In the ViewModel:

```
public List<MyObject> Items { get; set; }

public string Filter
{
    get { return filter; }
    set
    {
        filter = value;

        // Apply filter to list of Items here...
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you soo much for your help.It works when both listview and search bar are in same grid.But i would like to know can it be applicable when searchbar is in  another grid and listview is at another stacklayout.

Comment: yeah it is working according to my requirement..Thank you soo much again...

Comment: As long as they're on the same page it should work in any configuration :)